# How can I send data to my frontend js files in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am using ejs to render my html pages and am passing in data like this:

```
        collection.find({}).toArray(
            function (err, results) {
                res.render('index', {
                    results: results,
                    nav: nav
                });
            });
```

This works great, however I would like to send some data to my frontend js files to keep from using inline javascript in my rendered HTML.
is there a standard way to implement this?
I have tried renaming my js files with an ejs extension and rendering them as well, however this did not work.

Comment: Don't pass data directly to the .js files, and don't rename them, pass data in data-attributes on an element basis instead, and get that data with javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ajax, just create and endpoint what is send back JSON. For example:

**Server - getData**

```
collection.find({}).toArray(
  function (err, results) {
    res.json({data:results});
});
```

**Clinet - jQuery**

```
$.getJSON( "server-url/getData", function( result ) {
  // Do whatever what you want with this data
  console.log(result.data)
});
```

More details: [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

Comment: I have not used ajax before but I will look into this.